# Could not compile c++ with class property code definition

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, properties

Hey Guys I am trying to write a wrapper class for file handling in c++ and I was trying to use the "property" helper in visual-c++. I just started out so I created one property was trying to test it but it gave me a warning. 
Here's my **FileEngine.h** file:

```
#ifndef _FILEENGINE_HPP
#define _FILEENGINE_HPP

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class FileEngine
{

public:

    __declspec (property (put = setFileName, get = getFileName )) string filename;
    void setFileName(string);
    string getFileName();

    FileEngine();
    ~FileEngine();

};

#endif
```

Here's **FileEngine.cpp**:
    #include "FileEngine.hpp"

```
FileEngine::FileEngine() {}

FileEngine::~FileEngine() {}

void FileEngine::setFileName( string flname)
{
if (filename != "")
    filename = flname;
}

std::string FileEngine::getFileName()
{
if (filename == "")
    return NULL;
else
    return filename;
}
```

And this is the **main.cpp** file:
    #include "FileEngine.hpp"

```
int main()
{
FileEngine *file;
file = new FileEngine();
file->filename = "example.dll";
cout << file->filename << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This is the warning that I get when I compile it.
**warning C4717: 'FileEngine::getFileName' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause       runtime stack overflow**

Can someone explain me why this warning is coming up and what should I do to fix it? It'll be great help cause when I run it, stackoverflow does happen and the exe stops working.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem, but a better idea would be to note use property in the first place.

Comment: `getFileName` calls itself when it references `filename`.  There is your recursion.

Comment: Also don't import the entire std namespace.

Comment: Also note that its 'typically' considered a better practice to check if a string is empty via the `empty()` function: `if (!flname.empty()) { filename = flname; }`

Comment: @txtechhelp Thanks. I'll change my code to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the property in getter and setter.

```
std::string FileEngine::getFileName()
{
the filename access here will expand to getFileName(), as this is property...
if (filename == "")
    return NULL;
else
    return filename;
}
```

so declare member variable which will hold the property and then use member variable..

Comment: Thanks.....Now I got the problem. Is there any so called "good practice" to implement this. Thanks for the reply though.